# Why is $e^{i\pi}= -1$

Tags: exponential-function, irrational-numbers, pi, euler-mascheroni-constant, spherical-trigonometry

Why does $ e^{i\pi} = -1 $ ?

I know that this form can be used to for instance act on a bloch's sphere (quantum mechanics) using it as $ e^{i\pi/4} $ will do a $ \frac{\pi}{4} $ rotation on the $x-y$ plane

But I found no answer on the internet.

[EDIT]: Moreover the greats answers, I recommend [this really well made video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKtloBAuP74) for thoses who are not familiary of the Euler's identity.

[EDIT TO CLARIFY]:
Learning the basics of quantum information, I had to use this matrix: $ \begin{pmatrix} 1 && 0 \\\ 0 & e^{i\pi/4} \end{pmatrix} $ which is a gate named $ T(\psi) $ where $ \psi $ is a simple qubit as $ \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\\ \beta \end{pmatrix} $.

$ \alpha $ and $ \beta $ are just chances to get the classical qubit's state there, for instance $ \psi = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\\ \beta \end{pmatrix} $ gets $ \alpha^2 $ chances to be (as classical state) $ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $ (denoted $ |0\rangle $) and $ \beta^2 $ to be $ \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $ (denoted $ |1\rangle $) (both $ \alpha $ and $ \beta $ can be non null, this is known as superposition).

To visualize a qubit state we can use the **Bloch Sphere**
[The Bloch sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bL6pC.png)

Comment: This depends entirely on what you _mean_ when you write $e^{i\pi}$. What does that expression mean to you? Depending on your answer to that question, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvmuCPvRoWQ) has a nice explanation in it.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) to start

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093969/explanation-of-eulers-identity and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-ei-varphi-cos-varphi-i-sin-varphi

Comment: Thank you all, sorry for the dumb question, I was not aware of the Euler's identity, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093969/explanation-of-eulers-identity/2094009#2094009) helped me to get the concept introduced, i'll follow all your kindly pointed resources for a deeper understanding :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identities derived from Euler's Identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871240/identities-derived-from-eulers-identity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^{ix}=1+(ix)+\dfrac{(ix)^2}{2!}+\dfrac{(ix)^3}{3!}+\dfrac{(ix)^4}{4!}...=1+ix+\dfrac{i^2x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{i^3x^3}{3!}+\dfrac{i^4x^4}{4!}...$$

$$=1+ix-\dfrac{x^2}{2!}-i\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\dfrac{x^4}{4!}...=\left(1-\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{x^4}{4!}...\right)+i\left(x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}...\right) = \cos x+i\sin x$$

So:$$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$$

And you know the rest if $x=\pi$

Comment: Thank you, I would like to add a [link of a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKtloBAuP74) that I liked who treat this equation as you did

Comment: @AlexandreDaubricourt You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $e^z$ is defined to be the power series 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$$
This, and the power series for $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ lead to the identity
$$e^{i \theta} = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta)$$
from which $e^{i \pi} = -1$ follows.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$\exp(ix)=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

We have Euler's Identity $e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta + i \sin\theta$.

So, for $\theta =\pi$ we get $e^{\pi i}=-1$